# Is there a way to determine the order of a group or subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For example, I have a subgroup $H_n :=$ {$h\in S_n |h(n) = n$} as a subgroup of $S_n$, how am I supposed to find the order of $H_n$. If I have a small n, say 4, then I know that I can do a case by case analysis, since n is fixed, I only have to calculate the permutation of 3 elements, and so I just have to calculate the total number of permutations of the following: 1 cycle of 3 elements, 1 cycle of 2 elements and the identity, and this gives me a total of 6. However, if n is not specified, how am I supposed to calculate?

Comment: $H_n$ permutes every element of the set $\{ 1, 2, \cdots, n-1 \}$. So $H_n$ is actually nothing but $S_{n-1}$. You can also try to construct an explicit isomorphism between $H_n$ and $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: so it is (n-1)!?

Comment: Yes! That's what you got in your particular example: (4-1)! = 6.

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case you can make yourself clear that $H_n$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$: A permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that leaves $n$ fixed induces a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and on the other hand any permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ can be extended for an element of $H_n$.